# Google Sheets API Sharing Permissions

Tags: python, google-sheets, permissions, google-sheets-api, sharing

When I create a sheet from api `service.spreadsheets().create` , how do I share this sheet? I tried to access it from url, and adjusting the sheet id, but I get permission denied. How do I give access to xyz users?

Comment: What language are you using? Is it python?

Comment: @Tanaike yeah I'm using python

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.